# Kill command is not working for me in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I am unable to kill a process using kill command in Linux. And i cannot use Kill -9 to kill the process. can any one please help.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Maybe try pushing it to the limit with `-s SIGKILL`

Comment: @Rerito That's the same as `-9`. (Of course, `kill -KILL pid` looks better. ☺)

Comment: @CL. Indeed, I had checked the man after my comment but it was too late to edit/delete it afterwards ... I like the `SIGKILL` ... It's more frightening :D

Answer (score 3):

It state is most probably `D` then, the only state in which `kill -9` won't work. Most of the time the only fix is remount the filesystem or reboot.

Answer (score 2):

You can kill the running processes in linux by using kill -9 processId provided that you have right privileges  to stop the process. Provide more information if you need more help.